# Octave Get function_handle from vectorfunction with constants

Tags: octave

I've tried to get a vectorfunction like

```
  syms x
   fn=function_handle([x^2;1])
```

Output is @(x) [x.^2;1]

Thats leads of course in an error while calling fn with vectorarguments
(Dimensions mismatch)
Is there a way to avoid the issue?

I've tried `fn=function_handle([x^2;1+0*x])`

but the codeoptimation - or whatever - deletes the  0*x - term.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why syms? The point of a function handle is to have a numeric function. In any case, something like `ones(size(x))` may work (not sure with syms)

Comment: Is it important that this start off as a symbolic expression? The example you give is easier to implement directly as `fn = @(x) [x.^2;1+0*x]` (or use `ones(size(x))`.

Comment: Yes, it's important. I am developing an analysis package. At first I used octave functions, but I quickly realized that I had to use syms.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, what `function_handle` does here is reasonable, since the scenario you require here cannot be reliably predicted in advance. So I don't think there is an obvious option to change its behaviour.

You could deal with this in a couple of ways.

One way is to treat the function handle as unvectorised, and rely on external vectorization, e.g.

```
f = function_handle([x^2; 1]);
[arrayfun( f, [1,2,3,4,5], 'uniformoutput', false ){:}]
```

Alternatively, you could introduce a symbolic helper constant c, and call f appropriately. You can also create a wrapper function that uses an appropriate default constant. Examples:

```
f = function_handle([x^2; c], 'vars', [x,c]);
f( [1,2,3,4,5], [1,1,1,1,1] )

g = @(x) f( x, ones(size(x)) );
g([1,2,3,4,5])
```

or

```
f = function_handle([x^2; (x+c)/x], 'vars', [x,c]);
f([1,2,3,4,5], 0)

g = @(x) f( x, 0 )
g([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
Today, i'm happy of a solution i've found.
I turn the arrayfcn into a cellfcn:

```
    f_h_Cell=@(x, y) {x .* y, 0}
    
   nf = @(x) @mifCell2Mat (f_h_Cell (x (size (x) (1) * 0 / 2 + 1:size (x) (1) * 1 / 2,{':'} (ones (1, ndims (x) - 1)){:}), x (size (x) (1) * 1 / 2 + 1:size (x) (1) * 2 / 2, {':'} (ones (1, ndims (x) - 1)) {:})))
```

and then:

```
function res=mifCell2Mat(resCell)
  resCell=transpose(resCell);
  [~,idx]=max(cellfun(@numel,resCell));
  refSize=(size(resCell{idx}));
  resCell=cellfun(@(x) x+zeros(refSize),resCell,'uniformoutput',false);
  res=cell2mat(resCell);
endfunction
```

All automate calling following function
f=fcn(name,domain,parms,fcn);

so a simple f.nf([x;y;z]) call gives the result.

Of course it doesn't work, if there are numel's between 1 and say size=[10,10] of
eg size=[10,1], but so what ... In most cases it work's for me (until now: allways).

Oh, while i read my code just here, i've found a little bug:

```
refSize=(size(resCell{idx}));
```

must of course change to

```
refSize=(size(resCell{idx(1)}));
```

cause there a possible more than one max sizes in the idx, so i've picked the first. I do first a test of constant outDims, so that these workaround only occours, if there are constants. In the other cases (if all outDims contain domainvars) a simple anonymous function of a matrix-handle appears to the user:

```
f_h_Mat=@(x, y) [x .* y; x]

nf=@(x) f_h_Mat (x (size (x) (1) * 0 / 2 + 1:size (x) (1) * 1 / 2, {':'} (ones (1, ndims (x) - 1)) {:}), x (size
(x) (1) * 1 / 2 + 1:size (x) (1) * 2 / 2, {':'} (ones (1, ndims (x) - 1)) {:}))
```